# Chrome input type number renders trimmed

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

When input type is number Chrome renders input boxes different appearance, numbers in boxes are bottom trimmed.  Is there any way to fix it without change size of input controls?

Any help would be appreciated.

[See jsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/14371/)

[image: Render on Chrome]

Both text and number inputs renders with same appearance in Internet Explorer .

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="small">
    <input type="number" placeholder="Number"  value="8" class="form-control  input-xs">
        <br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Text" value="8" class="form-control  input-xs">
   </div>
</div>



input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance:textfield;
}
.input-xs {
    height: 22px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `line-height` of the `input-xs` class is messing with it.
If you take that away it looks ok. This has to be because not all browsers are supporting `line-height` inside `input`.

> While Chrome and Safari respect line-height val­ues on inputs,
>   Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Opera do not.

[From here...](http://joshnh.com/weblog/line-height-doesnt-work-as-expected-on-inputs/)

```
.input-xs {
    height: 22px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    /*line-height: 1.5; or set to 'line-height: 1'*/
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

[See Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/DTcHh/14373/)

Comment: I don't think you can call this a bug. There is a fixed height and a larger line-height, so there's an overflow. Sure it doesn't happen in other browsers, but that's because the other browsers don't support line-height in inputs. So, it's not a bug, it's a feature!

Comment: Thanks for the information! Is this still the case? http://joshnh.com/weblog/line-height-doesnt-work-as-expected-on-inputs/
_While Chrome and Safari respect line-height val­ues on inputs, Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Opera do not_

Comment: Yes, that. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) says Chrome does it wrong "according to the specifications". However, the actual specifications pointed to by MDN do not specifically say what should happen inside inputs.